# pylint import and dynamic path modification

Tags: python, pydev, pythonpath, pylint

My projects are generally structured like this:

```
projectname/
    __init__.py
    python/
        mymodule.py
    other_stuff/
    more_stuff/
```

where `__init__.py` contains the following code

```
import os
mypath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
__path__ = [mypath, mypath+"/python"]
```

This "skips" the `python` directory when importing to allow python code in the form `from projectname import mymodule` rather than `from projectname.python import mymodule`.

This appears to break pylint however, being unable to import any modules in the project despite `$PYTHONPATH` being set correctly. Creating a softlink `projectname -> python` in the `projectname` fixes things but isn't a suitable solution.

Any suggestions on how to fix this without altering the directory structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're kind of stuck. Pylint doesn't process your __init__.py file so unless you can find another way of getting that information into pylint, I don't think it's going to work. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I believe you are correct and there is no nice way to fix this. In the end I just worked around it in a Makefile rule.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you worked around this issue? I'm running into the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Chiggs if you found a solution I encourage you to [share your knowledge, Q&A-style](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to help [others who are trying to solve similar issues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36359210/5827215)

Comment: @Srikanth I used the soft-link hack described in the question.  It was a bit dirty, but in the makefile rule for pylint I created all the softlinks and then removed them again afterwards.